Replacement of strings within lists
i have a string list:
lis = {"a",{"b","c"},"d"}

...and would like to replace "c" with "Q", to give
res = {"a",{"b","Q"},"d"}

StringReplace works if I flatten lis beforehand, but I want to preserve the structure of lis.
Thanks for ideas for this simple question.

lis /. "c" -> "Q" ? Or do you mean Map[StringReplace["c" -> "Q"], lis, All] ?

Can you explain why you'd use StringReplace instead of just ReplaceAll?
